# Ajax combobox css removal

Tags: css, asp.net, ajax

I have used a Ajax Combobox, when I am binding it with my datasource I have few conditions on which background color defines,
but after the page load when hover comes on that List item of combobox then background color changes.
I dont want fix color background color will be change according to the conditions.
How to fix this issue can anybody help me in this.

Below is css which I have customized.

```
#ddlAdminTaskListNewLateralName  li

{
 /*background-color: #fff !important;*/
 color: #084B8A !important;
 padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
 }

#ddlAdminTaskListNewLateralName  li:hover {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer

```
 <ajaxControlToolkit:ComboBox  ID="ddlAdminTaskListNewLateralName"  runat="server" CssClass="WindowsStyle"  AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" MaxLength="20" ListItemHoverCssClass="ddlAdminTaskListNewLateralNameCss" AutoPostBack="True" DropDownStyle="Simple" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAdminLateralName_SelectedIndexChanged"></ajaxControlToolkit:ComboBox>

.WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist li {
        background-color: none!important;
        color: black !important;
        padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px !important;
         font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
    }

        .WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_itemlist li:hover {
            /*background-color: none !important;
color: #EFFBF2 !important;
text-decoration: underline !important;*/
        }

.WindowsStyle table {
top:0px !important;
```

}

I achieved the solution of my problem through above code.